# How would I create and update a time series using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to follow this schema design as it seems well though out: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

Ideally, I would like to record documents that capture data every second for a minute - just like in their early example.

I've run into 3 different hurdles:

**1)** I'm not quite sure how the schema should look - at the moment I have something like so:

```
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  timestamp_minute: String,
  type: String,
  values: [ Number ]
});
```

**2)** The 'values' array should be of length 60 (to store our one second data interval data points over a minute). How would I go about pre-populating this array with 0s?

**3)** How do I go about updating this array. I guess in my Node.js as I am getting frequent and consistent updates on the second, I could just use a index that gets increment and then resets after 59. Is there a way to use this index when trying to access 'values', e.g. using a mongoose update and '$set: { 'values.' + index: myValue }'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your schema should be:

```js
    var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      timestamp_minute: Date,
      type: String,
      values: [ Number ]
    });
```

2. You don't have to pre-populate it. In js, you can set any index you want even if the array is empty. However, if you want to do it:

```js
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      timestamp_minute: Date,
      type: String,
      values: {
        type: [ Number ],
        default: function() { return Array(60).fill(0); }
      }
    });
```

3. Yes. This is the way to do it as you see in the article.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, Amiram! I tidied up my schema based on your suggestions. As for point 3, I had some difficulties with syntax when using a variable as the index for the $set command (I would get a syntax error when doing "$set: { 'values.' + index: myValue }" - it doesn't seem to like concatenating a variable to the key?). So, instead I am using $push (e.g. "$push: { 'values': myValue }") to the same sort of effect... hopefully.